# Power BI is requiring at least one column to be summarized to display data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, summarization, no-data

I am trying to create a simple Power BI report to embed within an application. The purpose of this report is to simply display the rows that are being passed into it via Direct Query. However, if I disable the summarization of all of the columns the report refreshes with no data being displayed. Re-enabling summarization on one column causes the data to reappear. I do not require any summarization for the report and am wondering how to disable or circumvent this behavior.

Report with Summarization of one column

[image]

Report without Summarization of one column

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I really wanted to do was turn off the "Totals" footer which is an option in the "Format" tab of the visual itself. See https://radacad.com/removing-the-total-value-for-a-column-in-the-table-visual-of-power-bi-using-isfiltered for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to include key columns of the data feed to be sure you are displaying the rows as they come from the Direct Query. If the data feed doesn't have key columns or an index, you can generate one in SQL. Here's an example from an Oracle DB:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1)  AS "Index", 
column1, column2, ... columnN from table_name
```

Including the keys or an index will ensure you see every row in the table.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have added the index to the query however, the resulting report is summarizing the index as a total count. If I choose "Don't Summarize" the data is not displayed which seems to be the same behavior that I was encountering previously.